# Volume shader looks solid from outside

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

When I plug the scatter volume node into an object's volume, it only works correctly if the camera (or the viewport) is inside the object. If the camera is outside of it, it appears a mist-coloured solid. This is in both eevee and cycles. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Here's the shader:
[image]

Here's the scene- a floor, some pillars, and the box to which this shader has been plugged in. When I'm inside, it works
[image]

But when I'm outside of it..
[image]

So my problem is that the fog seems to be rendering on the inside, but not the outside. Flipping normals does nothing.

Comment: That doesn't sound like normal behaviour so something is going wrong on your system or you have something set up wrong. Please [edit] your question to include some screenshots of your material setup and results.

Comment: Wait, you're plugging it into the surface, or the volume? Also, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Edited the original post. I meant to say volume, not surface. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you have connected a shader to *both* the Surface and the Volume sockets of the Material Output. This gives the mesh both a volume and a surface. For purely volumetric objects you should not have a shader attached to 'Surface'.

Comment: As Rich says, you give the material a surface _and_ a volume, but if the surface material is not transparent, the camera cannot see the volume inside. Think of a closed cardboard box filled with smoke. You might see the smoke wen you're inside the box, but from the outside you only see a cardboard surface.